# Print array of chars by F() makro

Tags: c++, arduino

To reduce the usage of SRAM on my Arduino I'd like to print some text via the F() makro:

```
void setup() {
  char text[] = "i am just text";
  if(Serial) {
    Serial.println(F(text));
  }
}
```

But this throws the following error

```
C:\Temp\Software\arduino-1.8.10\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/WString.h:38:74:
error: initializer fails to determine size of '__c'

 #define F(string_literal) (reinterpret_cast<const __FlashStringHelper*>(PSTR(string_literal)))
C:\Temp\Software\arduino-1.8.10\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/WString.h:38:74:
error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

 #define F(string_literal) (reinterpret_cast<const __FlashStringHelper*>(PSTR(string_literal)))
```

But I don't really understand how to fix this. Could someone please help me to `Serial.println()` the `text` variable via `F()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `text` is a mutable `char[]`. Moving that to flash would be problematic. Changing the mutable in runtime, `text[0] = 'I';`, would not work as promised. Use the macro with a `const char*` instead - and do it around the string literal you want flashed.

Try:

```
auto text = F("i am just text");
// or: auto text = FPSTR("i am just text");
// or: static const char text[] PROGMEM = "i am just a text";

Serial.println(text);
```

When passing it to a function, you could add an overload for `const __FlashStringHelper*` (like `Print` and `Println` has):

```
void debug(const __FlashStringHelper *txt) {
    Serial.println(txt);
}
...
debug(text);
```

<sub>Disclamer: Untested</sub>

Comment: That worked. But my problem is that `text` is given as parameter to my debug function so I somehow need to print this by `F()`.

Comment: @alve89 It's hard to verify for me right now since I don't have the Arduino environment here, but, I added an example.

Comment: Thank you, but `text` is still a variable. I need to pass the string `"someDebugText"` to the `debug()` function where it should be printed via PROGMEM / F().

Comment: @alve89 If you have a `const char*` like `"someDebugText"` in SRAM, it wouldn't help if you could copy it to flash in runtime. It'd still occupy SRAM memory. The trick is to put all (most) static strings in the flash memory at compile-time. You could flash strings, like `"The error was: %S"` and `"not enough foo in the bar"` and then combine them in runtime using automatic variables that are used and then destroyed.

Comment: I understand that and it's a very good point! This might make it a bit simpler in my case because all the strings are constants as you described. But I can't understand why I need to write `debug(F("myTest"));` instead of `debug("myText")` and the string is processed in the function (and not while passing the parameter to that function). Isn't there a way to make it like `debug("myText")`?

Comment: @alve89 Not that I know of. `"myText"` is a `const char*` stored in SRAM. If you want it stored in flash memory, you need `F()`, `FPSTR()` or the `PROGMEM` modifier.